# L.Control.Search add layers to map when added to map

Tags: leaflet

I implemented a search functionality in my leaflet map using **L.Control.Search**. As the doc and the examples say, you have to pass for the **Control** the **layerGroup** you want to perform the search on. My layers are alreday clustered and added to the map but when I add the **L.Control.Search** the layers are added too and a mess is displayed on my map.

Here is my code of how I'm doing things :

```
var searchLayer = L.layerGroup([sibe, parc, daya, faune, biotope])
        //... adding data in searchLayer ...

    var searchControl = new L.Control.Search({
        layer: searchLayer,
        propertyName: 'titre',
        circleLocation: false,
        moveToLocation: function(latlng, title, map) {
           
            map.setView(latlng, 14); // access the zoom
        }
    })

    mymap.addControl(searchControl);

   var sibesMarkers = L.markerClusterGroup();
   var parcsMarkers = L.markerClusterGroup();
   var dayaMarkers = L.markerClusterGroup();
   var fauneMarkers = L.markerClusterGroup();
   var biotopMarkers = L.markerClusterGroup();

   sibesMarkers.addLayer(sibe);
   parcsMarkers.addLayer(parc);
   dayaMarkers.addLayer(daya);
   fauneMarkers.addLayer(faune);
   biotopMarkers.addLayer(biotope);
```

Is there any way to prevent the L.Control.Search from adding the layers to the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem here is that `Leaflet.markercluster` plugin and `Leaflet Control Search` plugin do not know about each other, so there must be some tricks used to make them work together.

First problem is that `L.control.search` call adds searched layers/markers to the map, which of course interferes with clustered markers. Solution to this is simply to remove layers with `.remove()` method after search control creation.

Second problem is that search control knows nothing about clustered markers, so upon successful search it moves to searched position and marks it, but if marker is clustered, it will stay clustered. Solution for this is to use it's `zoom` option to declare target zoom when moving to searched location. This zoom level has to used then also with marker cluster plugin `disableClusteringAtZoom` option, to ensure that target marker will not be clustered.

Code could then look something like this:

```
var searchLayer = L.layerGroup([sibe, parc, daya, faune, biotope])

var searchControl = new L.Control.Search({
  layer: searchLayer,
  propertyName: 'titre',
  circleLocation: false,
  zoom: 14
})

mymap.addControl(searchControl);
searchLayer.remove();

var sibesMarkers = L.markerClusterGroup({disableClusteringAtZoom: 14});
var parcsMarkers = L.markerClusterGroup({disableClusteringAtZoom: 14});
var dayaMarkers = L.markerClusterGroup({disableClusteringAtZoom: 14});
var fauneMarkers = L.markerClusterGroup({disableClusteringAtZoom: 14});
var biotopMarkers = L.markerClusterGroup({disableClusteringAtZoom: 14});

sibesMarkers.addLayer(sibe);
parcsMarkers.addLayer(parc);
dayaMarkers.addLayer(daya);
fauneMarkers.addLayer(faune);
biotopMarkers.addLayer(biotope);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I'll try it.