# Add Prunecluster to searchControl Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I have a bunch of markers clustered with PruneClucster this way :

```
for (i in propsEspeces) {
        for (j in propsEspeces[i]) {
            var marker = new PruneCluster.Marker(propsEspeces[i][j].geometry.coordinates[1], propsEspeces[i][j].geometry.coordinates[0], {
                data: propsEspeces[i][j].properties,
                icon: L.icon({
                    iconUrl: "markers/" + propsEspeces[i][j].properties.category_image,
                    iconSize: [60, 60], // width and height of the image in pixels
                    shadowSize: [35, 20], // width, height of optional shadow image
                    iconAnchor: [12, 12], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
                    shadowAnchor: [12, 6], // anchor point of the shadow. should be offset
                    popupAnchor: [0, 0]
                })
            })
            switch (propsEspeces[i][j].properties.GrandeCat) {
                case "AP":
                    marker.category = AIRES_PROTEGEES;
                    break;
                case "Veget":
                    marker.category = VEGET;
                    break;
                case "Faune":
                    marker.category = FAUNE;
                    break;

            }
            pruneCluster.RegisterMarker(marker);
        }
    }
pruneCluster.PrepareLeafletMarker = function(leafletMarker, data) {

        leafletMarker.data = data
        leafletMarker.setIcon(data.icon);
        leafletMarker.on('click', function() {
            mymap.setView(leafletMarker._latlng, 14)
            console.log(leafletMarker._latlng)
            console.log(layerSwitcher)
            carousselInner.innerHTML = "";
            textCaracteristiques.innerHTML = "";
            menaces.innerHTML = "";
            actions.innerHTML = "";
            for (var j in layerSwitcher) {
                //layerSwitcher[j].classList.add('forceRigth')
                $(layerSwitcher[j]).css("right", "35%")
                count.style.right = '35%';
                console.log(layerSwitcher[j])
            }

            var slides = leafletMarker.data.data.imgslides
            var men = leafletMarker.data.data.menaces


            //Section des actions

            if (leafletMarker.data.data.actions !== null) {
                actionTitle.style.display = "block";
                actions.style.display = "block";
                console.log("Les actions", leafletMarker.data.data.actions)
                var action = document.createElement('p')
                action.innerHTML = leafletMarker.data.data.actions;
                actions.appendChild(action)
            } else {
                actionTitle.style.display = "none";
                actions.style.display = "none";
            }

            //Section des menaces
            var menacesList = document.createElement('ul')
            if (leafletMarker.data.data.menaces !== null) {
                menaceTitle.style.display = "block";
                menaces.style.display = "block";
                console.log("Les manaces", leafletMarker.data.data.menaces)
                menaceTitle.style.display = 'block';

                for (var i in men) {
                    var menaceItem = document.createElement('li')
                    menaceItem.innerHTML = men[i]
                    menacesList.appendChild(menaceItem)
                    menaces.appendChild(menacesList)
                }
            } else {
                menaceTitle.style.display = "none";
                menaces.style.display = "none";

            }


            if (leafletMarker.data.data.taille !== null || leafletMarker.data.data.poids !== null || leafletMarker.data.data.repartition !== null || leafletMarker.data.data.reproduction !== null || leafletMarker.data.data.hauteur !== null || leafletMarker.data.data.temperature !== null || leafletMarker.data.data.feuilles !== null || leafletMarker.data.data.age !== null || leafletMarker.data.data.gg !== null || leafletMarker.data.data.climat !== null || leafletMarker.data.data.biodiversite !== null) {
                CaraTitle.style.display = 'block'
            } else {
                CaraTitle.style.display = 'none'
            }
            //Creation des  caractéristiques sur la taille

            if (leafletMarker.data.data.taille !== null) {
                texttaille.style.display = "block";
                console.log('tu entres')
                console.log("Les caractéristiques", leafletMarker.data.data.taille)
                texttaille.innerHTML = '<strong class="subtitles" +>Taille : </strong>' + leafletMarker.data.data.taille
            } else {
                texttaille.style.display = "none";
            }

            //Creation des  caractéristiques sur le poids

            if (leafletMarker.data.data.poids !== null) {
                textpoids.style.display = "block";
                console.log('tu entres')
                console.log("Les caractéristiques", leafletMarker.data.data.poids)
                textpoids.innerHTML = '<strong class="subtitles">Poids : </strong>' + leafletMarker.data.data.poids
            } else {
                textpoids.style.display = "none";
            }

            //Creation des  caractéristiques sur la repartition

            if (leafletMarker.data.data.repartition !== null) {
                textrepart.style.display = "block";
                console.log('tu entres')
                console.log("Les caractéristiques", leafletMarker.data.data.repartition)
                textrepart.innerHTML = '<strong class="subtitles">Répartition : </strong>' + leafletMarker.data.data.repartition
            } else {
                textrepart.style.display = "none";
            }

            //Creation des  caractéristiques sur la reproduction

            if (leafletMarker.data.data.reproduction !== null) {
                textrprod.style.display = "block";
                console.log('tu entres')
                console.log("Les caractéristiques", leafletMarker.data.data.reproduction)
                textrprod.innerHTML = '<strong class="subtitles">Reproduction : </strong>' + leafletMarker.data.data.reproduction
            } else {
                textrprod.style.display = "none";
            }

            //Creation des  caractéristiques sur la hauteur

            if (leafletMarker.data.data.hauteur !== null) {
                texthaut.style.display = "block";
                console.log('tu entres')
                console.log("Les caractéristiques", leafletMarker.data.data.hauteur)
                texthaut.innerHTML = '<strong class="subtitles">Hauteur : </strong>' + leafletMarker.data.data.hauteur
            } else {
                texthaut.style.display = "none";
            }

            //Creation des  caractéristiques sur la hauteur

            if (leafletMarker.data.data.temperature !== null) {
                texttemp.style.display = "block";
                console.log('tu entres')
                console.log("Les caractéristiques", leafletMarker.data.data.temperature)
                texttemp.innerHTML = '<strong class="subtitles">Température : </strong>' + leafletMarker.data.data.temperature
            } else {
                texttemp.style.display = "none";
            }

            //Creation des  caractéristiques sur la hauteur

            if (leafletMarker.data.data.feuilles !== null) {
                textfeuille.style.display = "block";
                console.log('tu entres')
                console.log("Les caractéristiques", leafletMarker.data.data.feuilles)
                textfeuille.innerHTML = '<strong class="subtitles">Feuilles : </strong>' + leafletMarker.data.data.feuilles
            } else {
                textfeuille.style.display = "none";
            }

            //Creation des  caractéristiques sur la hauteur

            if (leafletMarker.data.data.age !== null) {
                textage.style.display = "block";
                console.log('tu entres')
                console.log("Les caractéristiques", leafletMarker.data.data.age)
                textage.innerHTML = '<strong class="subtitles">Age : </strong>' + leafletMarker.data.data.age
            } else {
                textage.style.display = "none";
            }





            //Creation des  caractéristiques sur la hauteur

            if (leafletMarker.data.data.gg !== null) {
                textgg.style.display = "block";
                console.log('tu entres')
                console.log("Les caractéristiques", leafletMarker.data.data.gg)
                textgg.innerHTML = '<strong class="subtitles">Géographie et Géologie : </strong>' + leafletMarker.data.data.gg
            } else {
                textgg.style.display = "none";
            }

            //Creation des  caractéristiques sur la hauteur

            if (leafletMarker.data.data.climat !== null) {
                textclm.style.display = "block";
                console.log('tu entres')
                console.log("Les caractéristiques", leafletMarker.data.data.climat)
                textclm.innerHTML = '<strong class="subtitles">Climat : </strong>' + leafletMarker.data.data.climat
            } else {
                textclm.style.display = "none";
            }

            //Creation des  caractéristiques sur la hauteur

            if (leafletMarker.data.data.biodiversite !== null) {
                textbio.style.display = "block";
                console.log('tu entres')
                console.log("Les caractéristiques", leafletMarker.data.data.biodiversite)
                textbio.innerHTML = '<strong class="subtitles">Biodiversité : </strong>' + leafletMarker.data.data.biodiversite
            } else {
                textbio.style.display = "none";
            }


            //Creation des elements pour le slider
            var carousselActive = document.createElement('div');
            carousselActive.classList.add('carousel-item', 'active');
            var Firstimg = document.createElement('img');
            Firstimg.src = 'slider/' + slides[0];
            Firstimg.classList.add('d-block', 'w-100', 'img_slider');
            carousselActive.appendChild(Firstimg)
            carousselInner.appendChild(carousselActive)
            console.log(slides[0])

            for (var slide = 1; slide < slides.length; slide++) {

                var carouselItem = document.createElement('div')
                carouselItem.classList.add('carousel-item');
                var imgSlide = document.createElement('img');
                imgSlide.classList.add('d-block', 'w-100', 'img_slider');
                imgSlide.src = 'slider/' + slides[slide];
                carouselItem.appendChild(imgSlide);
                carousselInner.appendChild(carouselItem)
                console.log(slides);
                console.log("http://localhost/Carte_interactive_GIZ/slider/" + slides[slide])
            }

            categoryText.innerHTML = leafletMarker.data.data.category;
            categoryText.style.backgroundColor = leafletMarker.data.data.bgcolor;
            imgCategory.src = 'markers/' + leafletMarker.data.data.category_image;
            titreFiche.innerHTML = leafletMarker.data.data.titre;
            titreFiche.style.backgroundColor = leafletMarker.data.data.bgcolor;
            textDescription.innerHTML = leafletMarker.data.data.desc;
            video.src = leafletMarker.data.data.video;
            //Afficher Fiche
            fiche.style.display = 'block'

        });
        leafletMarker.bindTooltip(leafletMarker.data.data.titre)
    };



    pruneCluster.ProcessView();
    mymap.addLayer(pruneCluster);
```

I want to specify that the coordinates and the properties of the PruneCluster.Marker() are fetched from some geojson layers.

Now that I have all my markers on my map and clustered as I wanted. I want to add a searchControl on the prunecluster markers :

```
var searchControl = new L.Control.Search({
        layer: L.layerGroup([pruneCluster]),
        propertyName: 'titre',
        circleLocation: true,
        moveToLocation: function(latlng, title, map) {
            //map.fitBounds( latlng.layer.getBounds() );
            //var zoom = map.getBoundsZoom(latlng.layer.getBounds());
            map.setView(latlng, 14);


            //console.log("hey", this)

            // access the zoom
        },
        buildTip: function(text, val) {
            var imgCat = ""
            console.log(val)
            return `<div class = "searchResult">
                      <a>${text}</a>
                      <img src="markers/${imgCat}" alt="">
                  </div>`;
        }
    })
    mymap.addControl(searchControl);
```

When performing the research I get not found. What am I doing wrong? I search in the doc to see how I can do that with pruneCluster but found nothing. I have a long code because I'm doing a lot of stuff.

Comment: In what way is this question related to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/376089/add-prunecluster-markers-to-layergroup?

Comment: Why don't you try the same approach as in hte answer to the question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/375090/l-control-search-add-layers-to-map-when-added-to-map?

Comment: @TomazicM I tried it but didn't work.

Comment: Then edit the question with that code that you tried and didn't work.

Comment: The code I'm provinding is the one that didn't work. my previous question that you mentionned is using MarkerCluser not PruneCluster it's a different thing and I used the same approach but didn't work.

Comment: @TomazicM I did pragram my own search engin. Thanks for your feedback.